# HackRF One and IoT overloaded?

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, gnuradio, hackrf

I'm transmitting Z-Wave frames using HackRF One in loop, one frame every second. Has anyone clue why are some frames not transmitted? You can see  several too long gaps between frames on Waterfall (RTLSDR dongle + GQRX).

[image]

I'm pretty sure the problem is not the receiver. I use GRC blocks for this transmission, but when I use different tool, it's more reliable.

[image]

When I increase Interpolation on Rational Resampler (500, 750, ...) all frames are transmitted. However, these frames are not legitimate, because I Have to respect the formula:

[image]

40K sym/sec = data rate of Z-Wave

2 samp/sym = min for HackRF One

20M samp/sym = max for HackRF One

250 (1/250) = resampling ratio

Does this means the HackRF One is overloaded? I believe it should work somehow more reliable, because *hackrf_transfer* transmit pre-modulated frames reliable.

Comment: I’d try transmitting at 2 second intervals and observe for loss.